# When I use longtable, the table can't fit the whole text, is there any solution? Or is there a suitable way to change the page?

Tags: pdftex, longtable

Is there an effective way to automatically display text that cannot be accommodated to the next page?

For example, the code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|p{10cm}|}{\lipsum } \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The compilation result is as follows：
[image]

Comment: you are not really using a table at all it is a one row one column table with a p cell so it is just a single `\parbox` and boxes never break over a page.

Comment: if you are looking to frame a text that may break over a page look at tcolorbox (or the older framed or mdframed packages) longtable breaks pages between rows, so in a one-row table can not help.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thanks a lot for answering my question so quickly.  I actually created the large table, and part of it is a one-row table as you said. It turns out that longtable doesn't break the page. I will try to use `\parbox`, thanks a lot!

Comment: no `\parbox` is the _reason_ it does not break.

Comment: @David Carlisle   Sorry, my skills are not very good, I am asking again. I changed the code to the following.

    `\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\parbox{10cm}{\lipsum}} \\ \hline`
But still failed to break the page. If it is convenient, would you like to give a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a `\pagebreak` from time to time.

[image: x]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|p{10cm}|}{1. \lipsum[1-4] } \\ \hline
    \pagebreak
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|p{10cm}|}{5. \lipsum[5-8] } \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

With `longtable` you can run headers and footers that link the partial tables page by page.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}        
    \hline      
    \multicolumn{6}{|p{10cm}|}{\Large Main heading } \\ 
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{3}{l} {\footnotesize \emph{ \ldots{} from previous page.}} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|p{10cm}|}{ \Large Main heading } \\ 
    \hline
    \endhead
    
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\footnotesize \emph{to be continued in the next page \ldots{} }} \\ 
    \endfoot            

    \endlastfoot            

    \multicolumn{6}{|p{10cm}|}{1. \lipsum[1-4] } \\ \hline
    \pagebreak
    \multicolumn{6}{|p{10cm}|}{5. \lipsum[5-8] } \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the specific code! It was very useful for me.